# Android accessing data performance from internal storage Vs accessing data from external storage

Tags: android, android-intent

We are storing large amount of data i.e. above 1GB. we would like to know should i use internal storage for this because of security of data?

Also regarding performance, whether data accessible from internal storage is  faster than data accessible from external storage.

Answer (score 0):

On devices running Android 2.3 or below, you have no real choice but to store the data on external storage, as you will not have 1GB of space to work with on internal storage, and even if you did, users would threaten bodily harm to you for taking up so much space.

Most devices running Android 3.0 and higher have internal storage and external storage on the same partition. For those devices, you can store the data on internal storage. This *reduces* the number of people who can access the data, but those who root their devices can access internal storage if they choose to.

From a performance standpoint, internal and external storage should be identical, or close to it, on Android 3.0+, since they are on the same partition.